# Pro Tempore Moderator Nomination Thread

Tags: discussion, moderation, beta

As per the [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) blog post, I went ahead and created a thread to nominate Pro Tempore Moderators on this new site:

This is the basic structure of a Moderator nomination thread:

- The question should be community wiki.
- Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity.
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer, adding that they accept the nomination. Optionally they can write something about themselves.
- Self nominations are okay, and even encouraged. Most sites have not had sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is simply a way to say, “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.” Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.
  Include the bullet points (from above) to show what we are looking for.

According to the blog, Pro Tempore Moderators are generally selected 2 weeks after the public beta begins.

If you wish to nominate yourself or another, please read the [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) and post 1 nomination per answer.

Comment: going to make this question CW?

Comment: @Dave - I just flagged for moderator attention.  Hopefully, one of them can make it community wiki.  I don't see the checkbox for it/have the permissions...

Answer (score 1):

[DaveParillo](https://pm.stackexchange.com/users/76/daveparillo) ([meta](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/users/76/daveparillo)) - started playing around with [AskAboutProjects](http://www.askaboutprojects.com/users/629/daveparillo) about a week before this site was floated as an idea on [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/21226/daveparillo).

Comment: Your comments to questions and answers have helped people improve their quality.  We definitely need more of this.  Thanks!! +1

Answer (score 1):

[jmort253](https://pm.stackexchange.com/users/34/jmort253) ([meta](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/users/34/jmort253)) has been active on both the main pm site and the meta, submits good answers and questions and this site already has a software project management slant to it, so it would be nice to have a moderator who is not also a programmer or ex-programmer, just for a bit of variety!

Comment: Have often seen jmort dealing with edits, poor questions etc in a very friendly and welcoming manner.

Answer (score 0):

[Mark Phillips](https://pm.stackexchange.com/users/14/mark-phillips) -profile on other active sites like [AskAboutProjects](http://www.askaboutprojects.com/users/51/mark-phillips) and [LinkedIn Answers](http://www.linkedin.com/profile/qa?id=14123260&authType=name&authToken=loGa&goback=.npe_*1_*1_*1_*1) (see Answers tab)